# Update1 line of file with Gson

Tags: java

I want to Update my line of file,using Gson

Example
`{"titolo":"ex1","codice":"ex2","casa":"psw","autore":"ex3","copy":"ex4"}`
to
`{"titolo":"ex1","codice":"ex2","casa":"psw","autore":"ex7","copy":"ex4"}`

```
protected void aggiungiLibro(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File("E:\\libri.txt");

        if(!file.exists()) 
        {

            file.createNewFile();   
        }

            String titolo_libro = request.getParameter("titolo_txt");
            String codice_libro = request.getParameter("codice_txt");
            String genere_libro = request.getParameter("casa_txt");
            String autore_libro = request.getParameter("autore_txt");
            String casa_editrice = request.getParameter("casa_txt");

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);



            Libro lb = new Libro();
            String utJson;
            lb.setTitolo(titolo_libro);
            lb.setAutore(autore_libro);
            lb.setCasaEditrice(casa_editrice);
            lb.setGenere(genere_libro);
            lb.setCodice(codice_libro);
            lb.setCopieDisponibili("0");


            String input;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            utJson = gson.toJson(lb);
            boolean esiste=false;
            while((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(input.contains("\"codice\":\"" + codice_libro + "\""))
                {
                    Gson g = new Gson();
                    Libro libOld = new Libro();
                    Libro libNew = new Libro();
                    libOld = g.fromJson(input, Libro.class);
                    libNew = g.fromJson(input, Libro.class);
                    String copieString = libOld.getCopieDisponibili();
                    int copieInt = Integer.parseInt(copieString);
                    copieInt = copieInt+1;
                    libNew.setCopieDisponibili(String.valueOf(copieInt));
                    String jsonLibroOld = g.toJson(libOld);
                    String jsonLibroNew = g.toJson(libNew);
                    input.replace(jsonLibroOld, jsonLibroNew);
                    esiste=true;
                }

            }

            if(esiste==false)
            {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
                out.println(utJson);
                out.close();
                response.getOutputStream().print("Libro inserito");
            }
            else    
                response.getOutputStream().print("Copie aggiornate.");  

            bw.close();
            br.close(); 

    }

}
```

They update my file but it dosen't replace the line

Comment: What is the difference between the output you expect and the one you get? They look identical to me!

Comment: {"titolo":"ex1","codice":"ex2","casa":"psw","autore":"-----ex3------","copy":"ex4"} {"titolo":"ex1","codice":"ex2","casa":"psw","autore":------"ex7------","copy":"ex4"}